# The TLC5940 breakout board from sparkfun, init all servos at once. How can I init them one at a time?

Tags: arduino

I'm using these servos with the sparkfun TLC5940 breakout board:

http://www.mantech.co.za/datasheets/products/FITEC_FS90.pdf

That's all the info they have on the servos and I have no idea at what frequency they run at.

With this library:
http://code.google.com/p/tlc5940arduino/

I'm using 16 servos.
The problem is that the servos jitter like crazy.

There isn't any info on the net that tells me how to calculate the frequency or what the SERVO_TIMER1_TOP should be. Someone suggested to use 19500  and that value seems to get rid of most of the jitter. It's clearly not right as the servos still go out of sync if they don't reach their limits.

My problem is this:
If I call "tlc_initServos()", that call will try and set an initial start positions for the servos. The servos don't all have the same degree of freedom and setting all of them to one value will cause some servos to NOT reach their limit. The problem is also that with that many servos, if they all move at the same time, they pull some serious amps. This could cause some fluctuation on the pulses which cause them to go out of sync.

I'm using an arduino Pro mini, 16Mhz, 5V with a 3V external power supply for the TLC5940 breakout board.

Is there a way to init the servos one at a time?

How can I calculate what "SERVO_TIMER1_TOP" should be for those servos?